# PHP - While / Else error?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement, while-loop

I have the following php code:

```
<?php




if (!isset($_REQUEST['search'])){

    while(($write=mysql_fetch_array($gamesearched)) != null){
    echo "Found!";
    }else{
    echo "No results";
    }

    }
?>
```

And it's giving me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else' (T_ELSE) in
>   C:\php\www\Gameplay\backgame.php on line 41

Comment: Because that is not valid syntax... `else` can only be paired with `if`.

Comment: Edited the topic, please read the code again (?)

Comment: You've still got the `else` paired with the `while`, not with the `if`.

Comment: So what should I do ?

Comment: Welcome ;). If you find an answer, no need to close this topic. What you can do is "accept" the answer below: press the check on the answer that fixes it. If there isn't one, you might want to write down your own solution and mark that as the correct answer. The goal is to have a clear question-and-answer page here, not a forum-topic to throw away :). Also, I don't see what the other question you asked is about that is different from this one, don't open duplicates! Good luck with your code though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, a `while` statement can't have an `else` clause. You need something external to the `while` that can tell you if it was executed at least once.

How about something like this?

```
$total = mysql_num_rows($gamesearched);
if ($total > 0) {
    while (($write=mysql_fetch_array($gamesearched)) !== false) {
        echo "Found!";
    }
} else {
    echo "No results";
}
```

In this case, I've looked up the total number of rows found before I start, but I could also have started by setting a counter to zero and then incrementing it inside the while loop. That would look something like this:

```
$total = 0;
while (($write=mysql_fetch_array($gamesearched)) !== false) {
    $total++;
    echo "Found!";
}
if ($total == 0) {
    echo "No results";
}
```

Note that `mysql_fetch_array()` returns `false` if there are no more rows, so I've updated the while condition for you as well.

All that being said, there are good reasons not to use `mysql_*` functions in new code. See this question for more details, and some better alternatives: [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

PHP doesn't support `else` in `while` statements. You will need to use a sentinel instead.

Comment: else is not in while actually. but i know what you meant

Comment: @A.S.Roma: It is in the *statement*, even if it isn't in the *block*.

Comment: Yes but not in "while statement" :)

Comment: @A.S.Roma The *statement* that you have written is `while (something) { ... } else { ... }`. That is not valid PHP - the only valid form of a while statement is `while (something) { ... }`. The error message means exactly what it says - unexpected "else".

Comment: Ok, this can be understood in both ways...no more arguments, agree

Answer (score 1):

Where is your **`if`**??? You are missing `IF`

Also pay attention that if/else structure is as follows: `if() {} -> else {}`
You still misplaced else, should be outside of if statement.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have misplaced the closing brace. See the possible correct codes below.

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
  while($write=mysql_fetch_array($gamesearched)){
    if($write != null) {
      echo "Found!";
    }else{
      echo "No results";
    }
  } 
}
```

or

```
while(($write=mysql_fetch_array($gamesearched)) != null){
  if (!isset($_REQUEST['search'])){
    echo "Found!";
  } else {
    echo "No results";
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited the topic, please read the code again (?)

Comment: That would only display the No Results message if the user isn't clicking in the search button that I have...

Comment: Since there isn't any while-else statement, how would I do?

Comment: Your requirement is not clear, check if the edited post is what you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

1)

```
if(xxxx){
   //do if
}else{
   //do else
}
```

2)

```
if(1):
    echo '123';
else:
    echo '456';
endif;
```